# BufferedStream Flush() doesn't write to MemoryStream()?

Tags: c#, bufferedstream

I was trying out `BufferedStream` over `MemoryStream`:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(64))
using (var bs = new BufferedStream(ms, 32))
{
    var buffer = new byte[] { 0xab, 0xab, 0xab, 0xab };
    bs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    bs.Flush();

    var actual = new byte[4];

    int cb = ms.Read(actual, 0, actual.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(cb);
}
```

It prints `0`. I was expecting it to print `4` since I figured `bs.Flush()` would write the `4` buffered bytes to `ms`.

Am I using `BufferedStream` wrong somehow or was my expectation simply wrong?

Comment: Not clear how serious you are but buffering a MemoryStream is of course nonsense.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Just fiddling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must write

```
ms.Position = 0;
int cb = ms.Read(actual, 0, actual.Length);
```

It is a **very** common error forgetting to rewind a `MemoryStream()` after writing to it :-) (let's say that I do it every time :-) )

Comment: Also, do this outside of the `using{}` because the repositioning will screw up the bufferedStream beyond usability.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If he doesn't want to write anymore there should be no problem. He `Flush()`ed the `BufferedStream()` so I think it is acceptable to assume the `BufferedStream` won't write anything on `Dispose()`/`Close()` (if there is no new `Write()`)... But yes, the fact that there is a single `Position` (and not a `ReadPosition`/`WritePosition`) can cause "fun" bugs :-)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Other problem: you can't create a `BufferedStream` that doesn't take ownership of the base `Stream`, so by `Close()`/`Dispose()` of the `BufferedStream`, the base stream will be `Close()`... (see [referencesource](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/bufferedstream.cs#L275))...

Comment: @HenkHolterman Or do a `ToArray()`... Both don't require the `Position = 0`